# В новом проекте Eclipse не генерируется файл R.java

Tags: android, eclipse

В одном из проектов обнаружились ошибки в файле **/scr/Name.java**. Оказалось, что в папке **/gen** отсутствует файл **R.java**.
Где-то прочитал, что можно сделать **Clear**, сделал для всех проектов, в итоге **R.java** пропал во всех и **Build** его не возвращает. 
Ладно с проектами, там ничего серьёзного не было, но теперь *при создании новых(!) проектов* наблюдается *точно такая же картина*.

Перед этим обновлял SDK

Comment: логи есть?

Comment: какие именно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрим [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/222472/android-type-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable) - хоть FAQ делай...