# Type R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, eclipse

Здравствуйте! 
Проблема очень серьезная. Довольно долго писала проект, и вот, он уже почти готов, но внезапно появляется такая ошибка: "Type R cannot be resolved to a variable". Пересмотрела много форумов, везде советуют сделать Clean, а потом вручную Build. Но это не работает. Папка gen как была пустая, так и осталась, ошибки так же остались.

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой. По рекомендации от [Barmaley ♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley) проверил наличие утилиты **aapt** в */platform-tools*. И её там не оказалось. Нашёл быстро, загуглив "aapt.exe".

[Нашёл здесь](http://goo.im/devs/udK/APKTool/aapt.exe), проверял он-лайн Dr.Web'ом, вирусов не обнаружено. Положил в */platform-tools*, запустил Eclipse, во все проекты, кроме одного **R.java** вернулось, в последнем сделал **Project -> Clean**, потом **Project -> Build**, и всё стало хорошо.

Comment: В последнем обновлении android-sdk утилита aapt была перемещена из `/platform-tools` в `/build-tools/version` и некоторые среды разработки просто не успели подхватить это изменение. Решается созданием символьных ссылок.

Answer (score 1):

Есть масса способов убить генерацию `R.java`, например:

1. Удалить компилятор ресурсов [aapt](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html) (находится в `<SDK_HOME>/platform-tools`)
2. Допустить ошибку в манифесте (генерация начинается с парсинга манифеста, и если в манифесте будет ошибка то генерации `R.java` не будет)
3. Может слететь конфигурация IDE (слишком общо, но кто сталкивался понимает)
4. Да мало ли еще - вспомню добавлю

На крайняк попробуйте запустить `aapt` с командной строки или через ant врукопашную, вы проведете восхитительный вечер :) зато будет что вспомнить.

В общем пробуйте

Answer (score 1):

У меня обычно возникает такая ошибка, когда я напортачу в XML файлах, будь то Manifest, Layout или любой другой XML.
[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)
Во втором пункте написал про манифест.

Советую проверить правильность всех XML.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это связано с тем, что в последнем обновлении `android-sdk` утилита `aapt` была перемещена из `/platform-tools` в `/build-tools/version` и некоторые среды разработки просто не успели подхватить это изменение.

По-хорошему проблема решается созданием символьной ссылки `/platform-tools/aapt -> /build-tools/version/aapt`. Или можно просто копировать файлик.